# trying to run commands in series

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, async.js

I am trying to run some shell commands in Node in series **WHILE** sending some information back to the client.

For that, I use a combination of **Socket.IO** and **Async.JS**.

I'm coming from Python where every command just runs flawlessly one after another. In my understanding Node is running everything at the same time, and it's great, but sometimes we need to run some stuff one after another.

Here's my server-side code:

```
io.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.on('convertstart', function(data) {
    async.series([
        function (next) {
          console.log('# STARTING -> room ' + room_);
          client.join(data.room);
          next(null, '');
        },
        function (next) {
          io.to(data.room).emit('step0');
          next(null, '');
        },
        function (next) {
          var some_commands = require('child_process').execSync('some bash commands');
          next(null, '');
        },
        function (next) {
          io.to(data.room).emit('step1');
          next(null, '');
        },
        function (next) {
          var some_commands = require('child_process').execSync('some other bash commands');
          next(null, '');
        }
    ],
    function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
  });
});
```

And here's my client-side code:

```
socket.on('step0', function(data){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".uk-progress").css('width', i + '%');
        $(".uk-progress").text(i + '%');
    }, 300 * i)
   })(i);
  }
});

socket.on('step1', function(data){
  for(var i = 10; i < 30; i++) {
    (function(i){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".uk-progress").css('width', i + '%');
        $(".uk-progress").text(i + '%');
    }, 300 * i)
   })(i);
  }
});
```

The idea is to move the progress bar from 0% to 10% (with Socket.IO), THEN do some command-line operations, then move the progress bar from 10% to 30% (with Socket.IO again), and then again do some command line operations and so on.

Currently, this code just runs the whole stuff, without stopping between each operation. I want to note that each command-line command takes between 5 to 10 seconds, so there's no way the progress of the progress-bar is linear.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance...the problem seems to be related to the fact that `next()` is being used synchronously with the command it needs to wait for...but I believe that it actually should be passed as the success callback function for the command you need to run.

So:

```
function (next) {
   console.log('# STARTING -> room ' + room_);
   client.join(data.room);
   next(null, '');
},
```

would actually be:

```
function (next) {
   console.log('# STARTING -> room ' + room_);
   // Use next as the callback once client joins.
   client.join(data.room, next);  // use next.bind(null, '') if needed.
},
```

and so forth for each step.

Emit callbacks, I believe, are the second or third option, so: `.emit('step1', next)` or `.emit('step1',null,next)` should do.

https://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements)

And you're going to have to switch to an asynchronous child process execution to use callbacks, which is what you want, so: `.exec('some bash commands', next)`

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ReyHaynes, I just tried every possible combination, it doesnt work: I get the error `Error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting`...

Comment: the farthest I've been is when I do `client.join(room_, callback.bind(null, ''));` for the very first operation, and then it runs the second one (`io.to(room_).emit('step0');`) but it stops there. It doesn't run what's left.

Comment: I've tried to run the second command with some other stuff as you suggested, like `io.to(room_).emit('step0', null,next);` or  `io.to(room_).emit('step0',next);` and even  `io.to(room_).emit('step0', null,next.bind(null, ''));` but nothing worked as expected. Either it runs the whole thing in parralel, or it stops and doesn't run the rest.